# Measuring the entropy/reversibility of an expression

Tags: llvm, entropy

I am not sure that is the right name for the property I am looking for, I expect there is some (or even a lot) of research done on it but couldn't find anything.

I am trying to measure the "entropy" or "reversibility" of an expression (encoded in [LLVM-IR](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) but that's besides the point). This is a little vague, but mostly it is about how much information I can pass through a function and get outside. To try to be more precise, if I were to push true random values as input, how close to a true random value would I get as an output.

An upper bound would be to look at the total input bitwidth and total output bitwidth, and take the minimum bitwidth. An even tighter upper bound is to take a min-cut (in total bitwidth) through the dataflow graph. But I wonder if there is a generic way to approximate that number even better. Maybe a generalized form of known-bit analysis?

For example:

```
; entropy = 64bit (fully reversible)
define i64 @test_a(i32 %x, i32 %y) {
    %x0 = zext i32 %x to i64
    %y0 = zext i32 %y to i64
    %z0 = shl i64 %x, 32
    %z = or i64 %z0, %y0
    ret i64 %z
}

; entropy < 64bit (it is not possible to distinguish permutation of the arguments,
;                  nor their respective prime decomposition)
define i64 @test_b(i32 %x, i32 %y) {
    %x0 = sext i32 %x to i64
    %y0 = sext i32 %y to i64
    %z = mult i64 %x0, %y0
    ret i64 %z
}

; entropy = 32bit (min-cut is on %z0 and is 32bit, the LSB of %z is %x xor %y)
define i64 @test_c(i32 %x, i32 %y) {
    %z0 = xor i32 %x, i32 %y
    %z1 = sext i32 %z0 to i64
    %z2 = shl i64 %z1, 32
    %z = xor i64 %z2, %z1
    ret i64 %z
}
```

Is there a way to get even an estimate of that entropy? Maybe if I throw random values into the arguments and do an entropy analysis on the result it will give me a good idea?

I'm interested in this value because it feels related to the expected complexity of generating a circuit for that expression. For instance, if that expression is used for to extract a bank from an address computation, then a crossbar have greater chance of being sparse if the bank computation is low entropy.

Comment: Symbolic execution can give a formula that relates input values to output ones. Using it you can enumarate all possible values of output. There is a symbolic interpreter for LLVM IR called KLEE, even.

Comment: Yes, the more I think about it the less I think it is doable in a smart way. If that was easy I could solve expression equivalence (by xor-ing the two expression to test).